# am developing an app which need to send user selected data to webmail directly on submit without going to gmail compose page...

Tags: android

Am developing an app which need to send user selected data to  webmail directly on button submit without going to gmail compose page... 
i tried this below code but on submit it is going to compose page

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                String[] to = {"service@bikerepair.in"};
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This Mail is sent From AutoShed Mobile APP");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Services Needed : "+ sb.toString()+"\n"+"Need service on : "+date+"\n"+"Contact No : "+mobileNumber+"\n"+"Address : "+address1);
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

Comment: which error coming up?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124